# Hibernate Validator for proxied collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, bean-validation

I was trying to use the hibernate @Size validation on a OneToMany collection which is lazy initialized. If i am creating the parent entity with the children added in this collection, the validation is applied on trying to persist.
But if i simply find the parent entity and then do a getChildren(), the validation is not applied at all. I even tried putting the annotation on the getter. so i am using @Size(max=1) but still hibernate doesn't throw any exception even if children are more than 1. even EAGER fetch does not help.
As of now i had to put validation logic myself in the getter but obviously this is not the clean way. kindly let me know if someone has faced this issue before and if there is any elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event based validation is triggered on persist, update and remove. These are the events JPA defines for Bean Validation to occur (refer to the JSR-317 and JSR-338 specifications for more details). There is no validation when loading entities/associations from the database. The assumption is that persisted data is already validated. If you need to validate in your scenario, you need indeed to validate manually.

Comment: just to know, is there any elegant way to impose validations in lazy getter calls ? like interceptors or any other configuration? or adding java logic in the getter itself is the only way out ?

Comment: I guess an interceptor would work. How that would look like would depend on the technology you would like to use. You could also try to register a PostCollectionUpdateEventListener. You should get a even for the loaded collection at which time you could try to validate. I am still a bit skeptical about this though, w/o further understanding your usecase.

Comment: the case is simple, i want to enforce that the child collection has a max size limit imposed on it. like if i do a getChildren(), there should be a validation done that no of children being returned is <=Max. now i can do it through java logic in getter which i am doing now, but i was under impression @Size would do it more elegantly but it doesnt fire for loading as you also mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

[*Hibernate Validator provides two TraversableResolvers out of the box which will be enabled automatically depending on your environment. The first is DefaultTraversableResolver which will always return true for isReachable() and isTraversable(). The second is JPATraversableResolver which gets enabled when Hibernate Validator is used in combination with JPA 2.*](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4391)

Create your own implementation of `TraversableResolver` or use `DefaultTraversableResolver` and configure Hibernate Validator.

```
public class MyTraversableResolver implements TraversableResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean isReachable(
            Object traversableObject,
            Node traversableProperty,
            Class<?> rootBeanType,
            Path pathToTraversableObject,
            ElementType elementType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCascadable(
            Object traversableObject,
            Node traversableProperty,
            Class<?> rootBeanType,
            Path pathToTraversableObject,
            ElementType elementType) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say configure Hibernate validator, configure it for what? initializing the lazy loaded collections or enforce custom validations through if-else kinda logic ?